# How to set up a ranking system on a form written in HTML to rank total calculated values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a simple form in HTML. There are 3 sections (Section A, B and C). As the user fills out the form each section is calculated by displaying total points and percentage. I would like to rank the scores and display it in the ranking column but cannot seem to figure how to do it. For example if Section A has 4 points and Section B has 3 points and Section C has 0 points then section A would have the rank of 1, section B would have the rank of 2 and section C would have the rank of 3. Also having the ranking change as the form is being filled out would be ideal.

I am new to JavaScript, this is an assignment for class I am currently taking. I am having trouble on how to logically implement this. This is just a sample of my form. I really have a much larger form with more sections and questions. Please run my code so you can see a better visual. Any code snippets and advice that would help me will be appreciated. I understand that my code is not the best but like I said I am still learning also my professor wanted us to practice the way my code is structured so changing this code would probably result in some point deductions per my professor. So please if any code snippets are given please keep the same structure of my code.

I've tried using if statements in JavaScript but like I said I can't wrap my mind around how to logically do it. I appreciate it.

```
    <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Category |</th>
            <th>Points Possible |</th>
            <th>Points Awarded |</th>
            <th>Percent Achieved |</th>
            <th>Ranking</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">A</td>
            <td align="center">4</td>
            <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalASummary"></span></div></b></td>
            <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalAPercent"></span></div></b></td>
            <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">B</td>
            <td align="center">4</td>
            <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalBSummary"></span></div></td>
            <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalBPercent"></span></div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">C</td>
            <td align="center">4</td>
            <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalCSummary"></span></div></td>
            <td align="center"><b><div><span id="TotalCPercent"></span></div></td>
            <td bgcolor="#92d050" align="center"></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <th>Section A.</th>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><b>A.1</b></td>
           <td><b>Value</b></td>
           <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>a)</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Aa1">
                             <option value="0">0</option>
                             <option value="1">1</option>
                           </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>b)</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ab1">
                              <option value="0">0</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>c)</td>
           <td align="center">2</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ac1">
                              <option value="0">0</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td class="subtotal">Section A. Total</td>
           <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalA"></span></div></b></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <th>Section B.</th>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><b>B.1</b></td>
           <td><b>Value</b></td>
           <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>a)</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Ba1">
                             <option value="0">0</option>
                             <option value="2">2</option>
                           </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>b)</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bb1">
                              <option value="0">0</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>c)</td>
           <td align="center">2</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bc1">
                              <option value="0">0</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              </select></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td class="subtotal">Section B. Total</td>
           <td align="center"><b>5</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalB"></span></div></b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <th>Section C.</th>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><b>C.1</b></td>
           <td><b>Value</b></td>
           <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>a)</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Ca1">
                             <option value="0">0</option>
                             <option value="3">3</option>
                           </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>b)</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Cb1">
                              <option value="0">0</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>c)</td>
           <td align="center">2</td>
           <td align="center"><select class="select" onChange="calcC1();" id="Cc1">
                              <option value="0">0</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td class="subtotal">Section C. Total</td>
           <td align="center"><b>6</b></td>
           <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalC"></span></div></b></td>
         </tr>
       </table>

       <script>
       function calcA1R() {
         var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
         var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
         var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');

         var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
         var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
         var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;

         // returning the sum of the values
         return [parseInt(Aa1Val), parseInt(Ab1Val), parseInt(Ac1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
       }

       function calcA1() {
         displaySumA()
       }

       function displaySumA() {
         document.getElementById('totalA').textContent = calcSumA()
         document.getElementById('TotalASummary').textContent = calcSumA()
         document.getElementById('TotalAPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumA() / 4 * 100) +'%'
       }

       function calcSumA() {
         return calcA1R()
       }

       function calcB1R() {
         var Ba1 = document.getElementById('Ba1');
         var Bb1 = document.getElementById('Bb1');
         var Bc1 = document.getElementById('Bc1');

         var Ba1Val = Ba1.options[Ba1.selectedIndex].value;
         var Bb1Val = Bb1.options[Bb1.selectedIndex].value;
         var Bc1Val = Bc1.options[Bc1.selectedIndex].value;

         // returning the sum of the values
         return [parseInt(Ba1Val), parseInt(Bb1Val), parseInt(Bc1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
       }

       function calcB1() {
         displaySumB()
       }

       function displaySumB() {
         document.getElementById('totalB').textContent = calcSumB()
         document.getElementById('TotalBSummary').textContent = calcSumB()
         document.getElementById('TotalBPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumB() / 5 * 100) +'%'
       }

       function calcSumB() {
         return calcB1R()
       }

       function calcC1R() {
         var Ba1 = document.getElementById('Ca1');
         var Bb1 = document.getElementById('Cb1');
         var Bc1 = document.getElementById('Cc1');

         var Ca1Val = Ca1.options[Ca1.selectedIndex].value;
         var Cb1Val = Cb1.options[Cb1.selectedIndex].value;
         var Cc1Val = Cc1.options[Cc1.selectedIndex].value;

         // returning the sum of the values
         return [parseInt(Ca1Val), parseInt(Cb1Val), parseInt(Cc1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
       }

       function calcC1() {
         displaySumC()
       }

       function displaySumC() {
         document.getElementById('totalC').textContent = calcSumC()
         document.getElementById('TotalCSummary').textContent = calcSumC()
         document.getElementById('TotalCPercent').textContent = Math.ceil(calcSumC() / 6 * 100) +'%'
       }

       function calcSumC() {
         return calcC1R()
       }

       </script>
```

Comment: Juer José, que tienes un huevo de preguntas y en ninguna has aceptado ninguna respuesta...

Comment: Hi, this is not the place to ask how to do your assignment. I suggest you chop out every single function and features that you need to create the website that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Use conditional statements using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Cool you have done really great.
You just need to Sort

```
var list = {"A": 100, "B": 75, "C": 116, "D": 15};
keysSorted = Object.keys(list).sort(function(a,b){return list[a]-list[b]})
console.log(keysSorted);
```

Try to use the above logic and implement in your code.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you. This approach would result in too much code/ I have about 20 different sections and comparing all sections like that would be too much. I appreciate it.

Comment: Cool. But without comparing the section how you can rank. well you can try key value pair in which you will sort the key based on the value and then use the positions+1 as rank.